# Obtaining the difference between two datatables?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this code:

```
DataTable before = GetCustomerTable();
FixCustomerAddresses();
DataTable after = GetCustomerTable();
```

The `FixCustomerAddresses()` method doesn't add or remove any rows on the `Customer` table.  It just modifies certain existing rows.

I'd like to figure out which rows have columns that have been modified.  Is there a way to do this easily by comparing the before/after datatables?  I've seen this question on StackOverflow before but this scenarios were slightly different, and the proposed solutions (Merge + GetChanges; `AsEnumerable().Except`) don't work for me.  The resultant `DataTable` either contains all the rows, double the rows, or no rows at all.  The `DataTable` contains in excess of 35000 records.

`FixCustomerAddresses()` just runs a script on the DataBase.  There is no easy way to determine which rows have been changed within that method.  The DataTable contains the primary key, a few arbitrary columns, and of course the address fields.

Comment: Can you modify `FixCustomerAddresses()` so that it has the side-effect of keeping track of which rows it's updating?

Comment: What fields has the `DataTable`?

Comment: Edited the question to include the required info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally solved this was to export the DataTables to csv files, and then using a (free) diff library to generate a list of changed lines, and then just importing those rows into another DataTable.  This is fast enough to perform everything on the client so I did not need to change any database scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare all fields, for example:

```
var modifiedRows = from beforeRow in before.AsEnumerable()
                   from afterRow in after.AsEnumerable()
                   where beforeRow.Field<int>("Col1") != afterRow.Field<int>("Col1")
                      || beforeRow.Field<string>("Col2") != afterRow.Field<string>("Col2")
                   select beforeRow;
```

Comment: This solution is not feasible when considering the large number of records.  It seems I might have to consider a completely different approach, perhaps doing everything in the database and then exporting the changes.